# Create adhoc page relationship through kentico api when using pages data type

Tags: relationship, kentico

We can add page relationship in two different ways using named relationships and pages data type which is kind of [advanced content modelling in Kentico.](https://docs.kentico.com/x/DI2oAw).

if we go through named relationships then we can give a meaningful relationship between to content node by providing description. So, we get a relationship name called “is related to”(example). When we use this in practice, then we get [page A] {is related to} [Page B].

if we go through pages data type then we assign some content on the form tab, records are created in the “CMS_Relationship” table as ad-hoc via the “RelationshipIsAdHoc” column and there is no relationship name for this as such. It is marked as Ad-hoc. and Relationship name is also added page type name underscore some randon guid example abc.product_3d628a37-7637-4a21-b0b4-e1dd1a00a3bc

My question is when we try to use page data type and we need to add relationship through api code, then how can we add because in [kentico api](https://docs.kentico.com/api11/content-management/page-relationships#Pagerelationships-Creatingarelationshipbetweenpages) to add page relationship through api code **RelationShipNameID** is mandatory field. We don't have this **RelationShipNameID** as we are not going through named relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the way

Need to retrieve ad-hoc relatioshipnameinfo object, e.g. like this:

```
string codeName = GetAdHocRelationshipNameCodeName("fillclassnamehere", field);
var relationshipNameInfo = GetRelationshipNameInfo(codeName);
```

and then use is with API:

```
RelationshipInfoProvider.AddRelationship(leftSiteId, rightSiteId, relationshipNameInfo.RelationshipNameId)
```

Comment: I had to deal with this recently, just wanted to add how to get a FormFieldInfo object in case anyone needed it:
`var form = FormHelper.GetFormInfo(className, false);`
`var field = form.GetFormField(fieldName);`